# Subversion Error in svn mkdir svn://localhost/projet

Tags: svn

I try to create project svn with this command :

```
svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproject
```

i've this error :

```
svn: E135003: Unable to make name for 'svn-commit'
```

I'use french tutorial for creating svn in localhost, the tutorial is :

http://ericreboisson.developpez.com/tutoriels/install-subversion/

Answer (score -2):

**Sous Windows 7**
Maintenez la touche "SuperKey" ( ou "WindowsKey" en bas à gauche du clavier) enfoncée et enfoncez simultanément la touche "Pause" (en haut à droite du clavier). Dans la fenêtre "Propriétés système" qui vient de s'ouvrir, cliquez sur l'onglet "Paramètre système avancés" puis sur "Variables d'environnement". Dans les variables utilisateur cliquer sur "Nouvelle"

Saisissez dans Nom de la variable : `SVN_EDITOR`
et 
Saisissez dans Valeur de la variable : `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`

Enfin, ouvrez l'invite de commande en tant qu'administrateur et réessayé